# Entropy between elements and compounds

Tags: entropy

I have encountered this reaction when I am learning entropy:
[image]

I don't understand why there is an increase in entropy (said to be slightly larger than 0).

What I am thinking is:

1. both reactants and products are in the same states, so there isn't any change in entropy in terms of states.
2. both the reactant and products have the same number of moles i.e. the same number of molecules, which means in a constant volume, means the 'disorderliness is the same throughout the reaction, hence the entropy.

According to my lecturer and the internet, it is said that "Pure substances tend to have lower entropy than compounds" and "the pure substances are arranged 'tidier' than its compounds", which I don't understand why, especially the meaning of 'tidier'.

Therefore, I would like to ask what makes this reaction has an increase in entropy, and how can I determine that?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered change of entropy due exchange of heat ? dS=dQrev/T. Entropy change due structural changes adds to this one.